# keep variables from matlab script without using a function

Tags: matlab

I have an original script in matlab that runs a parameter file called "param_file.m" in the current working directory with the following code:

```
param_file; % this is used for parameter decleration before each run...
```

after running the above, I get to keep the variables...
and then I run another function that uses the previous parameters.

```
perform_work();
```

now I want to run the above in a batch mode, so I wrapped the above function as:

```
function doStuffUsingParams(param_file_name)
run(param_file_name);
perform_work();
```

unfortunately, run(param_file_name); doesn't return the variables like the first example.
any advise would be most appreciated.

thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. If it is not working at all, I mean it doesn't return the variables
   and there is an error while running the last line of the code

   ```
   perform_work()
   ```

   you might need to give the address of the first function to the
   **run** command properly. check the example on this [page](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/run.html#runexam1) for more information. Or you can put both functions on the same folder.
2. but if everything works well and there is no error:

   when you run the function from inside another function it actually
   runs but you should be aware that each function has its own
   workspace. the workspace will be erased after the function is
   terminated.

   After you run this line of code:

   ```
   run(param_file_name);
   ```

   it actually brings everything in the workspace.

   but after the function **doStuffUsingParams** is finished working it
   automatically clears the workspace.
3. I suggest you use a **disp** function after the second line to see the variables are actually there:

   ```
   function doStuffUsingParams(param_file_name)
   run(param_file_name);
   disp(param1)
   perform_work();
   ```

Comment: putting a breakpoint after run, I can see that you are unfortunately mistaken. doing run(...) doesn't return any variables into the workspace...

Comment: I mean put the Bp on the run and when stepping over you will see the function is working and the variables are invisible. then stepping out of that line still the variables should be there you can test it by an easy disp test. but after the main function passes the last line suddenly all the variables will inaccessible.